# js. Проверка на тип данных

Tags: javascript

```
  if (isNaN(n1) == false) {
    alert("Неверный тип данных");
  }
```

Верна ли эта запись? Сам понимаю, что скорее всего нет. Как правильно оформить проверку на тип данных на чистом js?

Comment: на какой тип данных? на число?

Comment: Да, на число. isNaN() для этого служит вроде как.

Comment: `if (isNaN(n1)) { выполняем код если NaN }`  или `if (!isNaN(n1)) { выполняем код если НЕ NaN }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**isNaN** - это проверка преобразования объекта к числу, но не совсем проверка типа данных. Проверяется, является ли объект типом *NaN* (отличным от числа). В JavaScript есть другие данные, например, бесконечность ∞, обозначаемая как *Infinity* или *NaN*, когда, например, происходит попытка 0 поделить на 0.

Для проверки типа данных можно воспользоваться функцией **[typeof()](https://learn.javascript.ru/types-intro)**.

```
var n = "12";
isNaN(n); // вернет false, т.к. может значение переменной n можно преобразовать в число
(typeof n)=='string'; // вернет true
```

Нужно понимать, когда стоит пользоваться этой функцией. Например, нам требуется вычислить результат введенных данных пользователем. Тогда в момент проверки валидации или подсчета можем воспользоваться проверкой.

```
// ...
if ( isNaN(userValue) ) alert("Введенное значение не является числом. Введите данные правильно");
```

Попробуйте в примере ниже подставить значения в поля и посмотреть результаты:

12

5e500

Infinity

Infiniti

(Здесь тип всегда будет равен "String", т.к. берется значение с Input'a. Более точно понять тип сможете выполнив команду 'typeof ' в консоли или через alert() напрямую)

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
function check(){
 var data = document.getElementById("data").value;
   if ( isNaN(data) )
     alert("This is not a number");
   else
     alert("This is number!");
}

function gettype(){
 var data = document.getElementById("data").value;
  alert(typeof data);
}

</script>
<input type="text" id="data" />
<input type="button" onclick="check()" value="Проверить isNaN" />
<input type="button" onclick="gettype()" value="Получить тип" />
```

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте так:

```
if (typeof n1 !== 'number') {
   alert("Неверный тип данных");
}

typeof undefined // "undefined"

typeof 0 // "number"

typeof true // "boolean"

typeof "foo" // "string"

typeof {} // "object"

typeof null // "object"  (1)

typeof function(){} // "function"
```

Answer (score 0):

Из комментариев к вопросу:

> - на какой тип данных? на число?
> - Да, на число.

```js
function isNumeric(val) {
  if (typeof val === "number" && !Number.isNaN(val) && val !== Infinity && val !== -Infinity) {
    return true;
  }
  
  return false;
}

console.log(isNumeric(10)); // true, распознает десятичные
console.log(isNumeric(0o744));// true, распознает восьмеричные
console.log(isNumeric(0xff));// true, распознает шестнадцатиричные
console.log(isNumeric(3.1415));// true, распознает с плавающей точкой
console.log(isNumeric(10e10));// true, распознает экспоненциальную запись
console.log(isNumeric(Infinity));// false, не реагирует на Infinity и -Infinity
console.log(isNumeric(NaN));// false, на NaN тоже
```